# Decoding serialized data from protobuf in javascript

Tags: javascript, deserialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf.js

I try to decode protobuf message in javascript using protobuf.js, but get the error: `Error: invalid wire type 4 at offset 3`.

I have 'message.proto' structure like this:

```
package proto;

message Data {
  repeated ObjRecord records = 1;
}

message ObjRecord {
  uint64 object_id = 1;
  Obj object = 2;
}

message Obj {
  bytes serialized_object = 1;
}
```

Code:

```
// message stored in blob
let proto = new Uint8Array(await new Response(blob).arrayBuffer());                              
protobuf.load("./message.proto",
    function (err, root) {
        let message = root.lookupType("proto.Data");
        let decoded = message.decode(proto); // error
    });
```

How can I get bytes of each inner Obj message and decode it?

Comment: please add the code you are using which throws the error and provide the data as well. thanks

Comment: @Peter, I add piece of code. Message is stored in blob.